# clojure swap! update map of maps

Tags: clojure

```
(def tables 
   (atom 
   {:tableA {:occupied false :party nil} 
    :tableB {:occupied true  :party nil}
    :tableC {:occupied false :party nil}}))
```

I'm attempting to update the state of ":occupied" to true for one of the  tables.
This works for me:

```
(assoc-in tables [:tableC :occupied] true)
```

however I have not been able to get it working using "swap!". Here is what I am attempting to do:

```
(swap! tables assoc-in [:tableC :occupied] true)
```

which gives me an error:

ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Atom  clojure.core/swap! (core.clj:2162)

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This works for me - try restarting your REPL or redefining `tables`. Looks like at some point you redefined `tables` as a map instead of an atom.

Comment: @RobBuhler how did you solve it? By restarting repl? If so, I'm voting to close the question.